# Would an Alderson Disk be possible around a White Dwarf Star?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, megastructures

I have seen the ideas of Alderson Disks around Sun-Like Stars. It would be utterly massive to say the least. Would an Alderson Disk be more 'possible' around a White Dwarf Star, how large would it be around an average White Dwarf Star? Assuming this Disk has an Earth like atmosphere, how would such a thing look and act?

Answer (score 3):

First, you want a *very old, very cold* white dwarf.  One such star (but you don't want it because of the neutron star nearby) has a surface temperature under [3000 K](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0488v1) ... this is called [white hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence), but the temperature would put it firmly in the category of a [red dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dwarf), if it weren't a white dwarf.

Such a dim star can have a "habitable zone" less than 1% the size of the Sun's (150 million km -> 1.5 million km or less), reducing the size of any "disk" with area by the same amount as the luminosity (over 10000-fold).  Even more importantly, stars cooler than the white balance setting on your monitor shouldn't subject you to UV or worse radiation.  Of course, that's still over a million km in radius, so I wouldn't book a trip just yet.

To come as close as I can think to plausibility, I'd suggest you postulate a natural ring of debris around the dwarf.  You would like to condense some of that into a sturdy artificial moon, but your ring is somewhat closer to the star than the habitable zone.  So you make it into an edge-on disk so the amount of light it absorbs is less, giving it a habitable temperature.  With one of these you make a small gap in the rings over time, using up all the material in the gap.  You can spin the built habitat to provide pseudo-gravity.  Then you make another similar structure a little further in or out.  As your collection grows, you loosely tether these objects together in a higher order frame with transport links, moving them each toward your optimal orbit.  Eventually you have enough that you can call them collectively a thin or partial Alderson disk.

Comment: That makes sense. How large would such an object be around the white dwarf? It would be much smaller than something around the sun, yes.

Comment: I clarified the habitable zone dimensions above.  As for the minimum size of a "partial Alderson disk" ... I think it could be one satellite, as long as the flat side isn't facing Earth.  Otherwise it's a partial Ringworld. :)